# Saving just model & weights in Keras (in single file)

Tags: python, keras, saving-data

I have Python code that generates a deep convolutional neural network using Keras. I'm trying to save the model, but the result is gigantic (100s of MBs). I'd like to pare that down a bit to make something more manageable.

The problem is that `model.save()` stores (quoting the Keras FAQ):

- the architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model
- the weights of the model
- the training configuration (loss, optimizer)
- the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.

If I'm not doing any more training, I think I just need the first two.

I can use `model.to_json()` to make a JSON string of the architecture and save that off, and `model.save_weights()` to make a separate file containing the weights. That's about a third the size of the full `model.save()` result. But I'm wondering if there's some way to store these in a single self-contained file? (Short of outputting two files, zipping them together, and deleting the originals.) Alternatively, maybe there's a way to delete the training configuration and optimizer state when training is complete, so that `model.save()` doesn't give me something nearly so big?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [save](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L2554) function of a Model has a parameter exactly for this, called include_optimizer, setting it to false will save the model without including the optimizer state, which should lead to a much smaller HDF5 file:

```
model.save("something.hdf5", include_optimizer=False)
```

Comment: Thank you--worked beautifully. Except...is there any way to silence its warning when I load it: "UserWarning: No training configuration found in save file: the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually."

Comment: When loading, you can avoid the warning by using the `compile=False` keyword: `keras.models.load_model(name, compile=False)`