# Using Tensorflow, How can I load weights generated from LSTM into CudnnLSTM Model?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I trained on LSTM model with tensorflow, can i load weights generated from LSTM into CudnnLSTM Model? My LSTM code is

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size)
outputs, (c, h) = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell,
                                    input_seq,
                                    dtype = tf.float32)
```

CudnnLSTM code is

```
cudnn_cell_fw = cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(num_layers = 1,
                                    num_units = hidden_size,
                                    direction = cudnn_rnn.CUDNN_RNN_UNIDIRECTION,
                                    input_mode = cudnn_rnn.CUDNN_INPUT_LINEAR_MODE,
                                    dtype = tf.float32)
outputs, (h, c) = cudnn_cell_fw(inputs = input_seq)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving just model & weights in Keras (in single file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786713/saving-just-model-weights-in-keras-in-single-file)

Answer (score 0):

I tried collecting weight and bias of LSTM as:

```
frozen_graph_path = './train_one_lstm_model.pb'
frozen_graphdef = get_graphdef(frozen_graph_path)
for node in frozen_graphdef.node:
    if (node.name == 'rnn/lstm_cell/kernel'):
        lstm_weight = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(node.attr['value'].tensor)
    if (node.name == 'rnn/lstm_cell/bias'):
        lstm_bias = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(node.attr['value'].tensor)
```

Then i send them to CudnnLSTM node

```
weight_shape_0 = lstm_weight.shape[0]
weight_shape_1 = lstm_weight.shape[1]
new_cudnn_weight = np.zeros(((weight_shape_0 + 2) * weight_shape_1), dtype = np.float32)
index = 0
for i in range(weight_shape_0):
    for j in range(weight_shape_1):
        new_cudnn_weight[index] = lstm_weight[i][j]
        index += 1

for j in range(weight_shape_1):
    new_cudnn_weight[index] = lstm_bias[j]
    index += 1

frozen_graph_path = './train_one_culstm_model.pb'
frozen_graphdef = get_graphdef(frozen_graph_path)

for node in frozen_graphdef.node:
    if (node.name == 'cudnn_lstm/opaque_kernel'):
        ori_cudnn_weight = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(node.attr['value'].tensor)
        node.attr['value'].tensor.CopyFrom(tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(new_cudnn_weight))
        new_cudnn_weight = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(node.attr['value'].tensor)
```

So the CudnnLSTM node get same weights and bias as LSTM. However, when i send same input, the output is different.